# Would partitioning the table improve the performance of this GROUP BY query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, partitioning

I have a MySQL table say `data_table`

```
mysql> desc data_table;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| prod_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date       | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cost       | double           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This table has around 700 million rows. I have created indexes on `prod_id` and `date`. I need to perform a query like this -

```
SELECT `id`, `prod_id`, WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) AS period, SUM(`cost`) AS cost_sum
FROM `data_table` GROUP BY `prod_id`, `period`;
```

My question is -

*Will partitioning the table on months (~20 partitions) improve the performance of this query?*

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; `DESC` is less descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITIONing` will *not* help at all.  Not `BY RANGE`; not any other flavor.

The query must read every row in the table; partitioning does not change that fact, nor can it speed it up at all.

The query, as it stands, has an unrelated problem.  Which `id` is it supposed to return for each `GROUP`?  Answer: It will return a 'random' `id`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out and It seems you are right. Query on partitioned table actually ran slower. Also, the query in the question is not a real query I am using, its just an example, actual query is much more meaningful.

Comment: @Optimus -- and the actual query may run faster with partitioning (but I doubt it).  Too many things factor into optimization; need to use the actual query.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the number of records and the SQL query you have written I would say yes, if done correctly Partitioning would help a lot. I would go further and suggest Range Partitioning on the Date field. This is a very common Partitioning method and works well and is easy to implement.

You don't mention the release of MySQL you're running so you'll have to do some additional reading [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) to understand what your MySQL release supports.

You can also run this SQL at the command prompt.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE %partition%
```

This should report back with "have Partitioning = Yes" or "Partition_engine = yes" depending on your relase.

Comment: I'm sorry you 'accepted' this answer.  It is _wrong_.

Answer (score 1):

If you see that there are a lot of queries based on week number, it makes sense to permanently store the week number as a column. We can save on the calculation during select.
The ideal strategy is to know what queries you will run and then design your tables accordingly.

Comment: I agree, In my case it makes a lot of sense to store `WEEKOFYEAR(date)` as a separate column and create an index on it... thanks..